# How do I include static html in release bundle for ReactNative Android?

Tags: react-native

I've got a WebView that uses a local file `require` to display web content.

```
  <WebView
    source={ require('./inline_web_view/inline_web_view.html') }
    injectedJavaScript={ scripts }
    scrollEnabled={ this.props.scrollEnabled || false }
    scalesPageToFit={ false }
    style={{
      width: this.state.width,
      height: this.state.height,
    }}
    onNavigationStateChange={ (navState)=> this.onNavigationStateChange(navState) }
  />
```

This works perfectly on ios and Android in dev mode, however, it seems as though the HTML file is not being included in the android release bundle.

How can I add it to the bundle?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in React Native.

The quick workaround is to load the content in a different way in iOS and Android. iOS will work as you described, but for Android release, you need to copy the static files into your native app assets folder (i.e. android/app/src/main/assets) and load the content with an `{ uri: 'file:///android_asset/-your-path-' }` source.

See [this post](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7924) for full details and a complete example.

Comment: { uri: 'file:///android_asset/-your-path-' } //without S on android_asset